# Create Instance of Class with String VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created some custom classes:

- class1
- class2
- class3
- etc.

I need to create an instance of these classes given the input from an excel worksheet.  So the input would return the string, "class1", "class2", "class3", etc.

In vba, I need to be able to say:

```
Set instanceOfClass = New "class1" 
'using whichever string was returned from the worksheet, if that makes sense?!
```

Can anyone help; is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Probably wrong, but maybe : `Set instanceOfClass = New Evaluate("class1")` But you may have to create a function that generate an object depending of the string you are inputing : @Comintern : I think that it's the name of the class that is coming as a string, not a parameter.

Comment: @R3uK - That makes much more sense. I think I read that completely wrong.

Comment: @Comintern : Damn it! I was posting my answer^^, same question indeed, too bad the OP didn't accept the answer! BTW, just a question, does `CreateObject` recognize custom classes? Like `Set instanceOfClass = CreateObject("class1")`?

Comment: FWIW, you should be using a common interface for your class factory (see the linked duplicate) instead of returning `Object`. The calling code seems to point toward the need for some degree of polymorphism. [I'd give this topic in documentation a read.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5357/object-oriented-vba/19071/polymorphism)

Comment: @R3uK - I wish :-P - VBA uses internal CLSID registrations that are only available from the context of the runtime.

Comment: @Comintern : I thought so, but I was deeply hoping to be wrong!^^